# ¿Qué palabra(s) usar para indicar la diferencia entre "Diseño Gráfico" y "Diseñador Gráfico"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Realmente no se me ocurre qué palabra usar para diferenciar ambos conceptos.

"Diseñador Gráfico" es como el título de quien lo hace.
"Diseño Gráfico" es como el sustantivo, lo que hace.

Esto se aplica a otras cosas, por ejemplo "Desarrollador de Sistemas" vs "Desarrollo de Sistemas".

Lo que quiero es explicarle a una persona que no tiene que poner "Diseño gráfico" en el "cargo / puesto" de la persona, si no "Diseñador gráfico".

¿Cuál es el nombre que se le da a cada concepto?

Comment: Te refieres a si son ambas sustantivos o a cómo se llama el tipo de derivación de una en otra (El _diseñador_ es evidentemente un profesional que ejerce el _diseño_)?

Comment: Diseño es la profesión y diseñador el que trabaja en dicha profesión. No se de donde eres pero es como en ingles *Graphic design* versus *Graphic Designer*. Wikipedia: *A graphic designer is a professional within the graphic design*

Comment: @Diego me refiero al tipo de palabra, no tienen diferenciación en nombre? (Ejemplo, Verbo - Sustantivo), porque la primera por ejemplo son todas terminadas en ar/er (la primera parte)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si hablas del punto de vista laboral:

- **[Diseñador](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DuJB8dy) gráfico** es el ***cargo*** o ***título*** del puesto a ocupar.
- **[Diseño](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DuKP0H9) gráfico** es la ***profesión*** o la ***especialización***.

Comment: Muchas gracías. La verdad es que quería explicarle a la persona que cargaba los datos que no tenía que poner "Diseño gráfico" en el "cargo / puesto" de la persona, si no "Diseñador gráfico". El tema es que no sabía que palabra usar para explicarle esto. El tema es que ya los anteriores estaban cargados de la primera forma, por ejemplo "Desarrollador de Sistemas", "Programador", etc., en lugar de "Desarrollo de Sistemas" y "Programación"

Comment: Ok. Comprendo. Actualicé mi definición en el punto número 3. Deberías decirle a esa persona que cargue los datos en la sección de cargo/puesto por lo mismo que dices, el cargo o el puesto de la persona y no por la profesión o su especialización.